# Django testing not getting connected to the database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-testing

I am a newbie to django. In my first django app, I am testing one of my view to check login. Here is my view:

```
from testprjct.testapp.forms import LoginForm_form
from django.contrib import auth

def check_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm_form(request.POST)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        # I am hard-coding the credentials here just for testing
        user = auth.authenticate(username = 'test123', password = 'qwerty')
        if user is not None and user.is_active:

            auth.login(request, user)
            .....
```

This view is working fine when I am running the server and trying to login from the front-end. But failing when executing the test case for this view. Here is my test code for this view:

```
from testprjct.testapp.models import loginform

class ViewTests(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    loginform.objects.create(username='test123', password='qwerty')

def test_login(self):
    response = self.client.get('/login/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    response = self.client.post('/login/', {"username": "test123", "password": "qwerty"})
    print response
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

This always returns with 200 status_code (not redirecting to success page) by giving the message that login details are invalid.

Same is the issue when I am testing forgot password link in the login page. It works fine from the front-end when a valid email-id is provided. But from my test case it always gives me back the error message that the email-id doesnt have an associated user account, even though I am providing the same email-id that I gave in the front-end.

Any suggestions please? I have spent lot of time on this already trying to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django sets up a new database for testing, so it doesn't access your existing data. You need to create the data you need in the test itself, or in the `setUp` method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I created the object in setUp method, but still user is not getting authenticated. I am getting the same error message in the response that login details are invalid. I have edited the test case above in my original question